# Is it necessary to use preposition before gerund?

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct?

> 1. I'll come by looking for you.
> 2. I'll come looking for you.

If I don't use preposition 'by' will it be fine?

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are both grammatical and idiomatic, but they differ slightly and in meaning and in tone.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20by) has an entry for *come by*, showing that it's is a phrasal verb:

> **come by** to make a visit : *came by after dinner*

So your first sentence implies you are meeting at some prearranged place (it could well be the other person's residence, but it might also be, say, a bus stop or the person's place of work):

> I'll come by around six o'clock; be waiting on sidewalk and I'll pick you up.

Your second sentence *could* mean the same thing, but it also could be used in a more ominous way. Let's say I found out someone had been sleeping with my girlfriend, and I wanted to exact revenge. I probably wouldn't say:

> I'll come by looking for you.

because *come by* suggests a cordial visit. Instead, I'd be more likely to say:

> I'll come looking for you.

because *come looking* implies some kind of search. In that context, it's almost suggesting: "You can try to hide, but I'll find you anyway."

In the movie [*Taken*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/plotsummary), actor Liam Neeson doesn't tell his daughter's kidnappers, "I'll come by looking for you."

To answer the question in your title: no, a gerund does not require a leading preposition. Whether or not a preposition should (or could) be included depends entirely on the verbs used and the surrounding context.